# How to pass props to component

Tags: reactjs

If a reducer function can override a prop like this:

```
 return {...state, foo: action.payload };
```

Then if we have a component as such:

```
  const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.foo}</div>;
  }
```

How do I override in the same manner as above?

I want to do it like below but it doesn't work

```
<MyComponent {...props, foo: 5} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it the same way you would pass props to an `xml` element.

```
<MyComponent {...props} foo={5} />
```

You should also checkout the [Component and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) guide by react.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
<MyComponent {...props} foo={5} />
```